# Are car insurances in some states (in USA) typically sold for 6 months at a time?

Tags: united-states, car-insurance, florida, massachusetts

I recently moved from MA to FL and because my car insurance was about to expire, and I in any case need to get a Florida insurance, I have been shopping for a new car insurance online.

The car insurance that I had in MA was always for a 12 month period but it looks like all quotes that I have seen online (from GEICO, Progressive, MetLife, and others) talk about a "6 month premium". The web sites do not seem very clear on whether the insurance is for maybe for 12 months while perhaps the payments are just split into 6 installments(?)

Or are car insurances in Florida typically sold for 6 month time periods?

Comment: I've only ever had 6 month terms. I didn't even know 12 month terms were possible. I'm in Wisconsin.

Comment: Same experience in Illinois as Ben's in Wisconsin. It is cheaper to pay the entire premium in one lump sum than to pay monthly (the six monthly payments add up to more than total premium for six months because there is a "service charge" tacked on to each monthly payment, even if you authorize the insurance company to take the money from your bank account via ACH transfer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It varies per state. In NY I could do 6 or 12 months when I lived there.

In NC was the same, at least a few years ago.

In KY, to the best of my knowledge, you do a year.

There are also variations between states as to whether the *car* or the *driver* are required to be insured (NY is car, NC is driver, for example).